# EOF Error in Python

Tags: python, eof

Evening all,

I've been making a programme in Python which is more or less there but the final piece is causing an EOF error and I'm confused as to why or how to fix it!

```
myFile =open("positionfile.dat", "rb") #opens and reads the file to allow data to be added
positionlist = pickle.load(myFile) #takes the data from the file and saves it to positionlist
individualwordslist = pickle.load(myFile) #takes the data from the file and saves it to individualwordslist
myFile.close() #closes the file
```

With a bunch of code before it.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "P:/A453 scenario 1 +  task 3.py", line 63, in <module>
   individualwordslist = pickle.load(myFile) #takes the data from the file and saves it to individualwordslist
EOFError
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this exactly as your script is? I see know error. in your current program.

Comment: We need to see how data was written to the file.

Comment: You're complaining of an error caused in parsing a file. You show neither what's in that file nor how it was created. How could someone answer? If you need help with your coursework, talk with your teacher to ensure you aren't cheating.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `pickle.load()` two times on the same file. The first call will read the whole file, leaving the file pointer at the end of the file, hence the `EOFError`. You need to reset the file pointer at the beginning of the file using `file.seek(0)` before the second call.

```
>> import pickle
>>> wot = range(5)
>>> with open("pick.bin", "w") as f:
...     pickle.dump(wot, f)
... 
>>> f = open("pick.bin", "rb")
>>> pickle.load(f)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> pickle.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> pickle.load(f)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```